# c# set FontSize of TextBox

Tags: c#, textbox, font-size

How would I set the font size of a TextBox in c#. I can get the current size but it does not allow to set it.

```
public static Form client;
((TextBox)client.Controls[0]).Font.size = 16;
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You have to set the `Font` property. `Size` is a readonly property of `Font`.

```
var textBox = (TextBox)client.Controls[0];
textBox.Font = new Font(textBox.Font.FontFamily, 16);
```

Comment: so instead of: `textBox.Font.Size *= 1.1f;`
to do: `textBox.Font = new Font(textBox.Font.FontFamily, textBox.Font.Size*1.1f);`

Comment: @dajon so, I have to save the textbox content and re-populate the new one? Do you know why they have not made it the easy way?